# parse json request in php webservice

Tags: php, android, json, web-services

After searching a lot over internet I did not get any proper solution.
I am sending JSON data from android application to a webservice which is developed in php.

When I test the webservice through `Advanced Rest Cient Appication` I am getting my responce properly, but when I call the api it gives me `null` response.

Here is my android code from where I am sending my data to server:

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
          try {

           obj.put("name", email_string);
           obj.put("email", password_string);

          } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
          }

          try {
               HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url.toString());
               httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
               StringEntity se = new StringEntity(obj.toString());
               se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
               httppost.setEntity(se);
               HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
               Content = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
               Log.e("TAG", "response: " + response);
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
```

And here is my code for the php webservice:

```
<?php
error_reporting(1);
 $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'xxxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx');
 // Get data
$data = json_decode("php://input",true);
print_r( $data);
 $handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
 $raw_post_data = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $raw_post_data .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle); 

$data = json_encode($raw_post_data);
$data = json_decode( $data);
$data = (array) $data;
$myarray = split("&", $data[0]);

 $myarray2 = split("=", $myarray[0]);

  $myarray3 = split("=", $myarray[1]);

  if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 

  $qry = "SELECT emp_id, name, domain_name FROM Itl_login WHERE domain_name = '".urldecode($myarray2[1])."' and password='".urldecode($myarray3[1])."'";

 //echo $qry;
 $result = $conn->query($qry);


while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $json = array("status" => 1, "name" => $row["name"], "domain_name"=> $row["domain_name"], "emp_ID" => $row["emp_id"]);
}

 /* Output header */
 header('Content-type: application/json');
 echo json_encode($json);



?>
```

Please suggest me what I am doing wrong here.
Any help would be appriciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your control reaching till $qry = "SELECT?   $result = $conn->query($qry); what is the output of this line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works with Advanced REST Client application and not with your Android app it's because your are not parsing your attributes correctly.

I'd say it's something with this two lines

```
$myarray2 = split("=", $myarray[0]);

$myarray3 = split("=", $myarray[1]);
```

Your are getting your "null response" because the query is badly coded from the attributes